# Using HTTP2 as a protocol for device-side communication in an Azure IoT device

Tags: mqtt, amqp, azure-iot-hub, http2, azure-iot-edge

I was reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-protocols)  for Azure IoT Hub "Choose a device communication protocol" and curious about this paragraph:

> Consider the following points when you choose your protocol for
> device-side communications:
>
> Cloud-to-device pattern. HTTPS doesn't have an efficient way to
> implement server push. As such, when you're using HTTPS, devices poll
> IoT Hub for cloud-to-device messages. This approach is inefficient for
> both the device and IoT Hub. Under current HTTPS guidelines, each
> device should poll for messages every 25 minutes or more. Issuing more
> HTTPS receives results in IoT Hub throttling the requests. MQTT and
> AMQP support server push when receiving cloud-to-device messages. They
> enable immediate pushes of messages from IoT Hub to the device. If
> delivery latency is a concern, MQTT or AMQP are the best protocols to
> use. For rarely connected devices, HTTPS works as well.

Wouldn't HTTP2 work well as a communication protocol as well? Are there any
drawbacks to using HTTP2 compared to AMQP or MQTT?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP2 is not supported only HTTPS. If you need to tunnel through a firewall, you can use MQTT or AMQP over WebSockets on port 443.